# Why is called revert?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;



contract ExchangeTest {
   address owner;
   address addr;
   mapping(address => uint256) balancesToken;

   constructor() {
       owner = msg.sender;
       addr = address(this);
   }

   function EthToToken() public payable {
       balancesToken[msg.sender] += msg.value;
   }

   function TokenToEth(uint256 val) public payable {
       require(addr.balance >= val, "Not enougt eth");
       require(msg.sender == owner, "Not a round");
       address sender = msg.sender;
       balancesToken[sender] -= val;
       payable(sender).transfer(val);
   }
}
```

`VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

Maybe this is due to the fact that I transfer and withdraw funds for the contract not directly, but through another contract?  I also call contracts with web3.py.

Comment: Revert is thrown when calling TokenToEth, when EthToToken everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from edge cases such as not enough gas sent with the transaction or hitting the block gas limit, `TokenToEth()` can revert for multiple reasons:

1. `require(addr.balance >= val, "Not enougt eth");`

   Native balance of `addr` is lower than the value of `val` passed to the function.
2. `require(msg.sender == owner, "Not a round");`

   You're invoking the function from a different address than the `owner` (effectively the contract deployer).
3. `balancesToken[sender] -= val;`

   Integer underflow. Solidity 0.8 throws an exception if you're trying to subtract a larger number from a smaller one and store this value in an `uint` type (unsigned integer - no negative numbers). E.g. if you're trying to calculate "one minus two".
4. `payable(sender).transfer(val);`

   If `sender` is a contract, it needs to implement either the `receive()` or `fallback()` [special functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#special-functions) and not throw an exception while executing the function - otherwise it rejects the transfer.